# I am unable to use database in fragments in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sqlite

I am using Database in a fragment. However when I try to initialize my database Using the line:

```
database=openOrCreateDatabase("firstdatabase",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
```

It gives me an error saying:

> Error:(47, 55) error: cannot find symbol variable MODE_PRIVATE

This is my code:

```
public class Expenses extends Fragment{
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.expenses,container,false);

    final SQLiteDatabase database;
    Cursor c;
    ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<>();

    ImageButton img=(ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.img);
    final EditText commodity=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.commodity);
    final EditText amount=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.amount);
    ListView list=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list);

    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    final int day=calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    final int month=calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    final int year=calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    registerForContextMenu(list);
    database=openOrCreateDatabase("firstdatabase",MODE_PRIVATE,null);

    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Entered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String c=commodity.getText().toString();
            int a=Integer.parseInt(amount.getText().toString());
            String q2="insert into expenses(day,month,year,commodity,amount)values('"+day+ "','" +month+ "','" +year+"','"+c+"','"+a+"');";
            database.execSQL(q2);
        }
    });

    String q1 = "select * from expenses";

    c = database.rawQuery(q1, null);

    c.moveToFirst();
    do {
        String comm = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("commodity"));
        String amo = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("amount"));

        al.add(comm + "\n" + amo);
        ArrayAdapter ad = new ArrayAdapter(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,al);
        list.setAdapter(ad);
    }
    while (c.moveToNext());
    return v;
}
}
```

Comment: Use Class .MODE_PRIVATE.

Comment: @Adithya please tell me the complete line of code for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`.

This should work.

`database=getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase("firstdatabase",android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE ,null);`

Comment: Not working still...gives another error. Error:(51, 56) error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to CursorFactory

Comment: Still not working. The error says :  Error:(51, 61) error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to DatabaseErrorHandler

Comment: happy to help :)